# location.reload to a specific Tab using ASP.net MVC Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a page which loads multiple tables separated by TAB using bootstrap.

In the third tab called patient tab, I have an action being done inside a modal.

An ajax call in the view will call an action in controller, when the logic successfully returned to the view, it will call an alert box and to load the latest result set in the table, I put `location.reload()` function, HOWEVER, the page returns or load in the first TAB and not in the 3rd where I do some action.

Can I specify or force the Tab to be loaded?

here the snippet of the ajax call in view, since it is quite long

```
 }).promise().done(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Patient/SaveWeight',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(add_upd_obj_arr),
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.errMsg == '' || result.errMsg == "") {
                        bootbox.alert({
                            size: "small",
                            title: "Confirmation!",
                            message: "Successfully Updated.",
                            callback: function () {
                                $('#ModalVitalSign').modal('hide');
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        bootbox.alert(result.errMsg);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "small",
                        title: "Error!",
                        message: "There is an error while loading data."
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

I tried this, but does not refresh

```
 window.location.hash = tab_treatment_info; //id of the third tab
```